# Не корректно работает слайдер

Tags: html, css, slider

[image: Начальное состояние]

[image: Состояние после пролистывания влево]

[image: Ошибки в браузере]

Не корректно работает слайдер, а именно когда листаешь слайдер влево, слайды заканчиваются а слайдер продолжает листаться как бы в пустоту и в обратно направление уже не листается.

```js
$(function(){
    $('.company__container').slick({
        dots: false,
        slidesToScroll: 1,
        infinite: false,
        arrows: false,
        initialSlide: 0.15,
        responsive: [
            {
                breakpoint: 1920,
                settings: {
                    dots:false,
                    slidesToShow: 5
                }
            }
        ]
    });
});
```

```css
.company {
    margin-bottom: 160px;
    box-sizing: border-box;

    &__block {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        max-width: 392px;
        width: 100%;
        min-height: 119px;
        margin-right: 20px;
        background-color: $br-regular;
        border-radius: 8px;
        transition: all  0.6s ease-in-out 0s;
    }
    &__block:hover {
        background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
    }
    &__block:hover .company__path {
        transition: all  0.6s ease-in-out 0s;
        fill: $white;
    }
    &__svg {
        max-width: 270px;
        width: 100%;
        min-height: 99px;
        box-sizing: border-box;
    }

}
.company__container .slick-slide {
    display: flex;
}
.company .slick-list {
    margin-right: -20px;

}
```

```html
<div class="company">
                    <div class="container__specific">
                        <div class="company__container">
                            <div class="company__block">Изображение</div>
                            <div class="company__block">Изображение</div>
                            <div class="company__block">Изображение</div>
                            <div class="company__block">Изображение</div>
                            <div class="company__block">Изображение</div>
                            <div class="company__block">Изображение</div>
                            <div class="company__block">Изображение</div>
                            <div class="company__block">Изображение</div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Свойство `infinite` у Вас `false`, переключите на `true`. `infinite` - Скольжение по бесконечному циклу.

Comment: Поставил true, все равно слайды заканчиваются а слайдер продолжает листаться как-бы в никуда